# git how to update my master branch with a branch I been working on last 3 days?

Tags: git, github

I stopped working on my master branch because the code I was working on was not stable, so I created a new branch and have been working on it for three days.

I am happy with the changes, and would like to update my master (3 days old) with my current branch testing, what is the correct way to approach this?

Thank you all
[image]

Comment: Are other people also working on this same `master` branch, or are you the only person who has been using it for the past 3 days?

Comment: I am the only person for this, thanks!

Comment: Assuming your feature branch is just "ahead" of `master`, you may simply merge the feature branch into `master` and that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you committed all your changes in branch `testing` (or restored your unwanted uncommitted changes).

Switch back to branch `master`:

```
git switch master
```

Merge changes in branch `testing`:

```
git merge testing
```

Then delete branch `testing`:

```
git branch -d testing
```

If there are others also work on the master branch, sync with remote before pushing:

```
git pull --rebase
```